# Stacked Highcharts- How to plot a given point and remove color from the stack block

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, stacked-chart

I need to plot users office timings (in and out time) of a day in a graph using Angular JS.

For example I have reached office at 10 and then gone out for lunch at 1, then again came at 2 and then gone out at 2:30 for some work and so on.....

So in graph, y axis should show time from 10 to 6 and it should plot time on graph, like 1st it should point at 10, then on 1, then on 2 and then on 2:30 and so on...

So my questions are:

1) Using which graph, this could be achieved in a single bar?

2) I am using stacked highchart, however since stacked chart add the points, I am sending difference between the two data, so first I am sending 10, another I want to point at 1, so I am sending 3 and so on..., however it fill the entire block with a color, like from 10-1 one color, 1-2 one color and so on..., what I need is, first it should point at 10 then at 1,then at 2...and so on it should not fill it with any color.

What I have achieved so far is :https://plnkr.co/edit/CgnFfTbJ3BkyjHzErQGk?p=preview

but what I want to achieve is something like this

[image]

Please help.

You could also check the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">   </div>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var chart = {
    type: 'column'
  };
  var title = {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'   
  };    
 var xAxis = {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
 };
 var yAxis ={
   min: 10,
   max:18,
   tickInterval:1,
   title: {
     text: 'Total fruit consumption'
   },
   stackLabels: {
     enabled: false,
     style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
     }
    }
   };
   var legend = {
    enabled:false
   };   
   var tooltip = {
     enabled:false
   };
   var plotOptions = {
     column: {
       stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
           color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
          style: {
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
           }
         }
       }
     };
     var credits = {
       enabled: false
     };
    var series= [

      {  name: 'John',
        data: [1]
      },
      {  name: 'John',
        data: [0.5]
      },
      {  name: 'John',
        data: [1]
      }, 
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3]
      }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [10]      
      }];     

   var json = {};   
   json.chart = chart; 
   json.title = title;   
   json.xAxis = xAxis;
   json.yAxis = yAxis;
   json.legend = legend;
   json.tooltip = tooltip;
   json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
   json.credits = credits;
   json.series = series;
   $('#container').highcharts(json);

  });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a example using `columnrange` series.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/mzb3bpg2/

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Temperatures',
    data: [{
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      x: 0,
      low: 0,
      high: 10
    }, {
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      x: 0,
      low: 10,
      high: 16
    }, {
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      x: 0,
      low: 16,
      high: 20
    }]
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

[image]

[EDIT]

More complete one:
[image]

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/fzv2jd3c/